# How to comment in laravel .env file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I am working on a project in Laravel where I am storing some settings in .env file setting like few parameters for testing purpose and few parameters are for live working so I was just checking that is there any way to comment in .env file of Laravel.

Here is an example

```
/* Test Settings */
ACCESS_KEY=qwsdr
ACCESS_TOKEN=Bgcvfsx

/* Live Settings */
ACCESS_KEY=985AsdefG
ACCCESS_TOKEN=LFP994kL
```

Answer (score 439, accepted):

You use hash commenting:

```
# Test Settings
ACCESS_KEY=qwsdr
ACCESS_TOKEN=Bgcvfsx

# Live Settings
ACCESS_KEY=985AsdefG
ACCCESS_TOKEN=LFP994kL
```

Documentation: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#comments

Comment: Also on same line:
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true # may reveal e.g. MySQL password

Answer (score 36):

Please note that as of Laravel 5.8 [comment parsing in values has changed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#environment-variable-parsing).

In Laravel 5.7 an .env file containing `ENV_VALUE=foo#bar` would evaluate to `foo#bar`.

In Laravel 5.8 the same .env file would evaluate to `foo` instead, with `#bar` being seen as a comment.

To use the `#` character in a value, double quote the entire value like so `ENV_VALUE="foo#bar"`.

Answer (score 18):

Laravel use the [`vlucas/phpdotenv`](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#comments) package to parse `.env` file.

So according to [the doc](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#comments), you can comment like this:

```
# Test Settings
ACCESS_KEY=qwsdr
ACCESS_TOKEN=Bgcvfsx

# Live Settings
ACCESS_KEY=985AsdefG
ACCCESS_TOKEN=LFP994kL
```

Since [Laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#environment-variable-parsing), you can do something like this:

```
ENV_VALUE1=foo#bar
ENV_VALUE2="foo#bar"
```

will return:

```php
env('ENV_VALUE1'); // foo
env('ENV_VALUE2'); // foo#bar
```

> The [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#comments) package that is used to parse `.env` files has released a new major version, which may impact the results returned from the `env` helper. Specifically, the `#` character in an unquoted value will now be considered a comment instead of part of the value: