# Laravel 5.3 no .env only .env.dev

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm new to this team development. If I add .env file everything works fine but if I remove it there is an error `The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.`. How to make it work? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.env` file (or your environment) need to have an `APP_KEY` variable, which Laravel uses for encryption. You can generate a key with `php artisan key:generate --show`.

Comment: I mean If remove the .env it doesn't work. I have .env and .env.dev

Comment: and My team is .env.dev. I need to delete the .env

Comment: You don't remove the `.env` file, that is the environment file and is necessary. Typically you will have the `.env.example` file committed to your source control, and use that to create the `.env` file for the different environments.

Comment: If you want special Dev settings and Production setting then you can have two different `.env` files one for production with live credentials and one for Development with test credentials, and you can add comments also in `.env` file check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368016/how-to-comment-in-laravel-env-file)