# Laravel 5 load env file based on .env.master?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm planing to do something like, specifying what env file to load during application bootstrap time by creating a variable in .env.master such as ENV_VER = dev.env

This is because I have several branches such as development, release-1.1 and etc. Thus by loading the env file based on the name specified in a master env file, developers no longer have to copy and paste new variables into their local copy of .env and instead, just specify what version of env file to load in the master env file. By the way, I have several env files such as dev.env, 1.6.env etc.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure about your problem but I use comments in .env file for the same purpose, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368016/how-to-comment-in-laravel-env-file)

Comment: It was not what I'm looking for but thanks for your reply anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely, me myself I tend to "bend" a framework little bit everytime and there's always a way, not always the best solution though. I'm not giving a whole implementation here, just pointing you in some direction, that might work for you.

You can extend Laravel's base application class `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`, which contains `$environmentFile` variable storing environment file loaded during appplication bootstrap or possibly override function `loadEnvironmentFrom($file)` or `environmentFile()`. The whole logic is up to you.

So basically all you need to do in order to be able to "play" with `.env` loading is...

Create a new application class extending Laravel's one:

```
namespace MyNamespace;
...

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application as App;

/**
 * I'm doing alots of magic with .env in this class
 */
class Application extends App
{
    ... 

    /**
     * The environment file to load during bootstrapping.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $environmentFile = '.env.main';

    ...
}
```

And now, because we have a new *bootstraping* class, we have to tell Laravel we want to use it. So you'll have to modify `bootstrap/app.php` file in point where a new instance is being created:

```
...
$app = new MyNamespace\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
...
```

*Note:* For inspiration I recommend you to really look at `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` class.

Comment: Yeah, this was so close to what I wanted to do. Additionally, I also referred here: http://developers.ph/laravel-framework/laravel-5/how-to-setup-multiple-environment-for-laravel-5-developers-way/

Comment: I'd like to add that you could point to a different directory with ```$app->useEnvironmentPath('/var/www/projectname/custom-envs');```

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 5.5+ you can, maybe earlier, you can set your server have a APP_ENV environment or server variable that the process can see (apache, command line...)

this will allow you to use a suffix or file extension on your .env files for auto loading those files...

- APP_ENV=dev :: .env.dev
- APP_ENV=production :: .env.production

much easier than other solutions.

If you want to look into how this is done, it starts with

## 1. application bootstrappers

```
protected $bootstrappers = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\SetRequestForConsole::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders::class,
];
```

## 2. LoadEnvironmentVariables

first the environment is determined…

`\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::bootstrap` calls
`\Illuminate\Foundation\Application::detectEnvironment`

#### If

`--env={env}` for CLI then it will use that for APP_ENV.

#### Else

`\Illuminate\Foundation\EnvironmentDetector::detectWebEnvironment`
is called which uses a callback…

```
function () use ($config) {
            return $config->get('app.env', 'production');
        }
```

where `app.env` defaults to `env('APP_ENV', 'production')`

## 3 LoadConfiguration

`\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::bootstrap` calls...
`\Illuminate\Foundation\Application::afterLoadingEnvironment`
which eventually gets to

`\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::checkForSpecificEnvironmentFile`

which sets the environment file based on app env IF the file exists.

```
        $this->setEnvironmentFilePath(
            $app, $app->environmentFile().'.'.env('APP_ENV')
        );
```

allowing it to load the `.env.{APP_ENV}` instead of `.env`

### NOTE: Testing.

when running php unit tests. the Illuminate/Foundation will try to load the `.env.testing` file for configurations!