# Access config variable from env

Tags: laravel, git, environment-variables, config

I am building an application where I need to work on two git branch. For two branch, I need to maintain two database and every time I checkout to another branch I need to manually change database from `.env` file. (`env` file is included in `.gitignore` file)

Is there any way to access `config` variables from `env`? I tried this below way:

```
DB_DATABASE="${config('database.database')}"
```

But it is not working.

Note: I could do it by changing in `config/database.php` but I am in restriction that's why trying to find another way.

Comment: This is built to work the other way around, because an environment specific values need to be used by the configuration. The connection to the database reads from the `config` files, not directly from the `.env` file. That's why for example if you don't have `DB_DATABASE` in your `.env` file, it will still try to connect to a default database.

Comment: @nakov I know but I can't change `config` file.(Restriction)

Comment: Then look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43731580/1457270), this is the best approach I think.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the `.env` you could make multiple versions of your `config/database.php` where you simply enter the database settings instead of using the env:

old:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
```

new:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => '123.123.123.123',
```

You can then proceed to make stashes in your GIT, and simply apply the correct one depending on the branch you are on.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but my application is also live now so I can't change `database.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to have multiple `.env` files that contain the branch in the file name.

- `.env.production`
- `.env.development`

Don't forget to add these files to your .gitignore!

When switching branches you can manually change the name of the corresponding `.env.<branchname>` back to `.env`.

Comment: if he wanted to manually change the name he will proceed with what he already does :)

Comment: It's not perfect, but it's better than editing the contents of the file every time you switch branches.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked up a solution for you. I tried it on my environment and it works as you expect.

So in addition to what @Bram said, you can create branch specific `.env` files.

`.env.master` and `.env.develop` for example. Add both to `.gitignore`.

Then create a git `post-checkout` hook:

```
vim .git/hooks/post-checkout
```

With the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '\npost-checkout hook\n\n'
BRANCH_NAME=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
cp .env.$BRANCH_NAME .env
```

Add permissions to the file:

```
chmod u+x .git/hooks/post-checkout
```

Now when you checkout your `develop` branch the content of the `.env` file will be from `.env.develop` and same for master. This is the most automated way unless you want to extend the `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` file and change the

```
protected $environmentFile = '.env';
```

that way.