# Laravel does not read .env variables when there is a # character

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 7 when I do a simple:

```
$test_secret = env('TEST_SECRET');
echo 'Secret : ' . $test_secret;
exit;
```

the output is always:

```
Secret: 123
```

And my .env file is:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
TEST_SECRET=123#456#789
```

I am waiting for a response : "Secret: 123#456#789". And don't understand why I receive only "Secret: 123".

I know it is a trivial question, but I am on this problem...

Thanks

Comment: because `#` is used to declare a comment ... wrap the env var value in quotes

Comment: i am not sure it works or not but try 123\#456\#789

Comment: @lagbox this would probably worth an answer, however, I didn't check if there are dupes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57172073/4575350

Comment: @Cid I didn't mark it as duplicate

Comment: I'm usually a dupe hunter, however, this question, although simple, is nicely written (title and content are good) and will certainly help future readers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#` is used to declare a comment in the `.env` file. Wrap the var's value in quotes.

```
TEST_SECRET="123#456#789"
```